# Flashback Oracle Database - Shutdown abort

Tags: oracle, shutdown, flashback

If I killed a long transaction that is rolling back millions of deleted records, is there any risk to use SHUTDOWN ABORT on the DB before issuing a flashback command on it? Since the Database needs only to be in MOUNT state for the flashback, I would expect that there is no harm to do this instead of waiting for the rollback to complete.

Comment: There is no harm to shutdown your database in abort mode, since Oracle(and any respectable rdbms) garantee the ACID propreties.
Now after that you have to do a point-in-time recovery, to have your database in the consistant state juste before the delete occured.
You can also do a flashback database if you have the appropriates flashback logs.

Comment: i'm not sure that the flashback will be faster compared to the rollback...